# iOS WKWebview how to detect when I click on an image inside of <a> tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, wkwebview, watchos

I'm trying to change my `UIWebView` to `WKWebView` in my app (`Objective-C`).
I see `WKWebView` contain tag "a" and inside of tag "a" contain tag "image":

```
<a href="http://click.adzcore.com/xyz"><img src="http://www.abc.xyz/smart/images/bnr/yyy.png" width="320" height="50" border="0" alt="+alt[n]+" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/smart/count/frognote']);"></a>
```

I want detect when user click on image, so I do:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView )webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction )navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {

    if (navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated) {
        NSURL *url = navigationAction.request.URL;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
        return;
    }
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}
```

But this code is not correct because `WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated` is not catched when user click on image.

Comment: tag <a> which allows click function has a nested image that allows click function, so how you are gonna decide which one is clicked ? Can you try keeping just the image ? and then use `navigationAction` request url to verify image is clicked in combination with `WKNavigationTypeOther`.

Comment: @NeverHopeless: thanks your ideal but I can't control html code because it's returned from server. I tried use `WKNavigationTypeOther` but it's not correct because although you not click image then event click still is called.

Comment: For a test, once you get this html try to replace the a tag as per my suggestion (and make sure only the required tag replaces :) ) and first see it if is working then you can discuss this problem with the server team and remove the a part if it not necessary..

Comment: @NeverHopeless: thanks, I think it's good ideal but now I can not contact with the server team :(

Comment: ok what is the `navigationAction.navigationType` did you receive on a click ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless: it's `WKNavigationTypeOther`, but if you using `WKNavigationTypeOther` then when HTML is loaded on WKWebview, event click is called immediately although you don't click on image.

Answer (score 7):

After research I found a solution to solve my problem.
I don't use **WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated** to catch event click on image.

My solution:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {

    if ([navigationAction.request.URL.relativeString hasPrefix:@"http://click.adzcore.com/"]) {
        NSURL *url = navigationAction.request.URL;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
        return;
    }

    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}
```

It's OK for my task :)